# Hadith about slave who belongs to prophet

Tags: hadith-interpretation, prophet-muhammad, slavery

Can you tell is she maria al-qibtiyya in this hadith? because she is the only slave who gives birth to prophet child.

O people, impose the prescribed punishment upon your slaves, those who are married and those not married, for a slave-woman belonging to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) had committed adultery, and he committed me to flog her. But she had recently given birth to a child and I was afraid that if I flogged her I might kill her. So I mentioned that to Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) and he said: You have done well.
Sahih muslim 1705a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course it is not Maria (RA). She gave birth to the Prophet's son Ibrahim. It is unthinkable to accuse her of adultery.

The hadith mentions that a slave-girl committed adultery, and obviously, the child she had was the child of that adultery, not of the Prophet. The Prophet (SAW) did not only have one slave girl.